# Barrier voltage and temperature of a PN junction

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

Why does the barrier voltage of a PN junction decrease by increasing temperature ? Please if possible , i want to understand the inner physics of what happens

Answer (score 1):

Carriers can cross the junction when they have enough energy to surmount it.

At high temperature, there is more thermal energy around to add to the potential from voltage. Therefore less electrical energy is needed to get the peak energy to exceed the barrier.